# Mathematica Linear Regression

Tags: fitting, homework

[image]How do I create a  user-defined function  for linear regression without using the built in function. Essentially doing the steps one by one

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: DataX = List[_]
Mx = Mean[_]
DataY = List[_]
My = Mean[{_}]
X - Mx = DataX - Mx
Total[X - Mx]
Y - My = DataY = My
Total[Y - My]
Squared = (X - Mx)^2
SS = Total[Squared]
MxMy = (X - Mx) (Y - My)
SP = Total[MxMy]
co = SP/SS
c1 = My - (co) (Mx)

Comment: You may edit the question to include your code. You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: In my opinion, that question isn’t asking you to write your own linear regression code, but it would be worth clarifying if you haven’t already. It seems to me like it would be sufficient to write a function which prepares the data properly (by linearizing it) and then passes it to `LinearModelFit`.

Answer (score 2):

The Linear Regression Equation:

[image]

> b is the slope of the line and a is the y-intercept

[Image Source](https://www.statisticshowto.com/probability-and-statistics/regression-analysis/find-a-linear-regression-equation/)

Code only used `Total` and `Length` functions. Output is a list of two numbers which first one is the slope and second is the y-intercept:

```
myLinearRegression[x_, y_] := {(Length[x]*Total[x*y] - 
     Total[x]*Total[y])/(Length[x]*Total[x^2] - 
     Total[x]^2), (Total[y]*Total[x^2] - 
     Total[x]*Total[x*y])/(Length[x]*Total[x^2] - Total[x]^2)}

(*function output : {slope, y-intercept} *)
```

Example:

```
pts = {{1850, 1.3}, {1900, 1.6}, {1950, 3}, {1980, 4.4}, {2000, 6}};
```

Extract x,y part:

```
{ptsx, ptsy} = Transpose[pts];
```

Apply the function:

```
myLinearRegression[ptsx, ptsy]

(*Out: {0.0301743, -55.1574} *)
```

Compare to Mathematica built-in function:

```
Normal[LinearModelFit[pts, x, x]]

(*Out: -55.1574 + 0.0301743 x *)
```